# PIXI how to completely remove a sprite

Tags: pixi.js

I'm trying to completely remove a sprite from my game(acting as a death). All I could find online was:

```
sprite.parent.removeChild(sprite);
```

When I did this, the sprite stops rendering, but i'm pretty sure the sprite is still there, and my collisions are still being detected and it's causing lot's of problems. How do i completely remove the sprite from the scene?

Comment: I don't think PixiJS includes collision detection. Can you elaborate how you are detecting collisions? Perhaps it's just a matter of removing the sprite from the collision detection system, as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An entity gets deleted in javascript when there are no references pointing to it and GC (garbage collector) runs. Thus, to fully delete sprite you need to unlink it from everything.

If you have for example a `SpriteContainer` and within it you did

```
mySprite = new PIXI.Sprite(myTexture)
this.addChild(mySprite)
```

then you need to both use `removeChild` as you did, but also clear the `mySprite` reference.

Now please consider that GC runs are managed by the browser engine, so you might actually need to wait for a while before you see the sprite gone from memory.

And if you referenced it in chrome console, this too is a reference to the sprite and it won't get removed if you have it open.

To confirm the Sprite gets deleted, use browser's developer's tool, take a memory snapshot before and after deletion, and use a built-in comparision tool. If you see a delta of -1 for Sprite (and optionally also its Texture and BaseTexture), you're good. You can also manually call GC within developers' tools.

*Note: a PIXI.Sprite displays a Texture. Removal of Sprite does not necessarily cause removal of the Texture. PIXI has its own GC which will take care of abandoned textures, but if your object gets created and deleted often, it is better to keep the texture in memory so it doesn't cause stutter when loading up. To also clear contents of the sprite, please refer to `destroy` method, as documented here: http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html*